# How to exit a program in C++03 in a thread-safe manner?

Tags: c++, exit, c++03

I have a multi-threaded C++03 application (Linux-based) that I want to terminate immediately in a thread-safe manner.

I have tried using [exit(0)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/) but this destroys some static variables which are actively being used by another thread, causing that thread to access freed memory and destroyed objects, resulting in a core dump! Apparently the exit() function has a data race: "Calling this function destroys all objects with static duration: A program with multiple threads running shall not call exit (see quick_exit for a similar function that does not affect static objects)."

C++11 offers a thread-safe [quick_exit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/quick_exit/) function. But I don't have the ability to move this large application to C++11 at the moment.

I also don't want to spend effort trying to do clean termination/joining of threads. This is a very complex program and that would take a considerable amount of work.

Are there any other alternatives? I just want the program to exit immediately, no cleanup, no core dump.

Edit: What I'm really trying to do is replace abort() calls with something that won't create a coredump. And abort() is thread-safe, btw.

Comment: In other words: You took a shortcut (no proper shutdown logics) and now you regret it.

Comment: Perhaps `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);` ? :)

Comment: Side note: Many seem to avoid writing shutdown code. They think it saves them time. But... how do you then run tools like valgrind on the program?

Comment: "terminate immediately" creates oxymoron phrase when combined with "thread safe".  can-not be done.

Comment: What is the deal with the unconstructive comments on stackoverflow? If there is no use case for this, why is there a quick_exit() function in C++11?

Comment: @DarthAndroid SIGKILL is not too far off. What I'm really trying to do is replace abort() calls with something else because in certain cases I want it to exit immediately but without a core dump. BTW, abort() is thread-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get the effect you want by calling `_exit(status)` (note the leading underscore)

documentation:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to terminate: process or thread. It's usually safe to terminate a process and return control to OS but terminating a thread by "brute force" is usually a bad idea. The reason is many code and library are written with the assumption of being running in a single threaded environment. Killing a thread WILL leave some global variables in a "quantum state", which will cause problems for the code running in other threads. It's better to pay your effort to find some place in the said code and politely "ask" it exit.

Comment: I want to exit the process, not a thread. Sorry for the lack of clarity.